# Regression in spacing before lstlisting environment with version 2018/09/02 after paragraph break

Tags: spacing, listings

Anyone else noticed a difference in the spacing before a `lstlisting` environment since upgrading to version `1.7 2018/09/02`?

Here's a MWE with output with version 1.7 and version 1.6 for comparison.

I can get same output be removing the empty line before the `lstlisting` environment, but I'd rather not go through old files and do that. And it seems like wrong behaviour anyway.

Is this a bug?

Can anyone suggest a workaround to return things to the old behaviour?

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
Preceding paragraph.

\begin{lstlisting}{}
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
\end{lstlisting}

Subsequent paragraph.
\end{document}
```

### Output with `listings 1.7 2018/09/02`

[image: 1.7 output]

### Output with `listings 1.6 2015/06/04`

[image: 1.6 output]

Comment: There is a new `\leavevmode` in the definition. It looks rather odd there. Make a bug report to the author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I just saw this while comparing the style files. I emailed the maintainer. I'm still interested in the easiest temporary workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Update

This bug was fixed in `listings 1.8b 2019-02-28`.

## Original Answer

For an unknown reason lstlistings adds a \leavevmode in the code, you can try to disable it until the problem is resolved in the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\makeatletter 
\lst@AddToHook{PreSet}{\let\leavevmode\relax}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Preceding paragraph.

\begin{lstlisting}{}
xxx
\end{lstlisting}


Subsequent paragraph.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue too, Debian stable (buster) contains the buggy version `2018/09/02 1.7`.

The solution presented there did not work for me (I did not get the `\lst@AddToHook` to work), but following the advice from user `siracusa` (in my question [Extra space before listing (Debian stretch vs. buster)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506237/extra-space-before-listing-debian-stretch-vs-buster/506649)), the `listings` package can be installed locally into the same directory as the document as follows:

1. Download `listings.ins`, `listings.dtx`, and `lstdrvrs.dtx` from here: https://www.ctan.org/texarchive/macros/latex/contrib/listings
2. Extract the files by running `etex listings.ins`
3. Compile the document as usual by running `pdflatex`, the local version of the `listings` package is preferred

Thanks for the helpful responses and hints! :)