# Extra space before listing (Debian stretch vs. buster)?

Tags: spacing, listings

I'v recently upgraded from Debian stretch (oldstable) to Debian buster (stable). Among others, the package `texlive-latex-extra` (which contains the `listing` package) was [upgraded](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/texlive-extra) from `2016.20170123-5` to `2018.20190227-2`. Since then, compiling documents add extra space before listings.

Minimal example:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily,frame=single]
this is a listing
with two lines
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Compiled with Debian stretch, no extra space before the listing:

[image: Listing without extra space built on Debian stretch]

Compiled with Debian buster, extra space before the listing: [image: Listing with extra space built on Debian buster]

I've tried to set `abovesep` and `belowsep`, but the space defined there just adds to the space above the listing.

How can I remove the extra space before the listing? Thanks!

---

Based on `daleif`s comment below, I've recompiled the document on Debian stable (where extra space is added) with `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` to see all version information. The listings package has version `2018/09/02 1.7`:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.7.25)  30 AUG 2019 16:36
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
)
\lst@mode=\count88
\lst@gtempboxa=\box27
\lst@token=\toks15
\lst@length=\count89
\lst@currlwidth=\dimen103
\lst@column=\count90
\lst@pos=\count91
\lst@lostspace=\dimen104
\lst@width=\dimen105
\lst@newlines=\count92
\lst@lineno=\count93
\lst@maxwidth=\dimen106

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty
File: lstmisc.sty 2018/09/02 1.7 (Carsten Heinz)
\c@lstnumber=\count94
\lst@skipnumbers=\count95
\lst@framebox=\box28
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.cfg
File: listings.cfg 2018/09/02 1.7 listings configuration
))
Package: listings 2018/09/02 1.7 (Carsten Heinz)

No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
\c@lstlisting=\count96
[1

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./test.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
listings.sty    2018/09/02 1.7 (Carsten Heinz)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
 lstmisc.sty    2018/09/02 1.7 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2018/09/02 1.7 listings configuration
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1826 strings out of 492615
 23459 string characters out of 6131390
 83138 words of memory out of 5000000
 5809 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3808 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 26i,4n,32p,151b,1010s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr
/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 27204 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Might be an idea to list your package versions as well, if you place `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and recompile, then the used package versions is written to the log. My guess are changes to how lipsum works, you can also test this by replacing the lipsum command with manual text

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, it's not related to lipsum at all since it also happens with text entered manually (that was how I discovered the problem). I've posted the log output from `pdflatex` with `\listfiles` here: https://gist.github.com/fd0/b1c10c747b2beab6cd61997269fe92ad Any further ideas? :)

Comment: Please put that into the question instead. We generally does n ot like to get stuff from sites outside of this side, also your may become unusable for other in the future in that link disappears

Comment: Note that my upstream TeXLive 2019 have a newer listings version that your link shows.

Comment: You could try with the newest version of `listings`. Download the [.dtx and .ins files from CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/texarchive/macros/latex/contrib/listings) and run `etex list­ings.ins`. The created files can be copied to your local folder with the .tex file, so that LaTeX uses them instead of the installed ones. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: I've added the version information inline, thanks for the hint @daleif I then downloaded the newest `listings` package as suggested by @siracusa and it works: the odd space is gone! I'll write an answer myself. Thanks for your time!

Comment: It is probably down to the fact that the debian TeXLive might not be 100% up to date. (one of the reasons why I use upstream TeXLive instead of getting it from a Linux dist).

Comment: This was a bug in `listings 1.7 2018/09/02`. It was fixed in `listings 1.8b 2019-02-28`, but this was not released in time to make it into Debian Buster.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help, I've marked this as a duplicate and posted my solution for the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the version of the `listings` package (`2018/09/02 1.7`) on Debian stable contains a bug. This is also described here: [Extra space before listing (Debian stretch vs. buster)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/506237/extra-space-before-listing-debian-stretch-vs-buster)

The solution presented there did not work for me (I did not get the `\lst@AddToHook` to work), but following the advice from user `siracusa`, the `listings` package can be installed locally into the same directory as the document as follows:

1. Download `listings.ins`, `listings.dtx`, and `lstdrvrs.dtx` from here: https://www.ctan.org/texarchive/macros/latex/contrib/listings
2. Extract the files by running `etex listings.ins`
3. Compile the document as usual by running `pdflatex`, the local version of the `listings` package is preferred

Thanks for the helpful responses and hints! :)